# Strategy to update UITableView by Parse query

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have a news feed application which provides tons of news everyday. There is a UITableView showing the news items in descending chronological order.It will shows a certain number (for example, 20 items) per page. When I drag up the tableview, it will load more items (for example, the next page). Here comes a problem, for example:

- There are totally 47 items, 1,2,3,... 47
- The items per page is 20.
- The first time it shows 47,46,45,...28
- It will show 27 ... 8 when I drag up my tableview to load more data
- There are more news items updated in the server, for example, 49,48 were added
- The next time when I call "loadmore" in my client side. The server will return 9, 8, ... 1 instead of 7,6, ... 1

The query coding is like this one:(The skip is the value of total number of items I currently have)

```
    query.limit = 20
    query.skip = skip

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
```

Any method to overcome this issue? Thanks

Comment: i am not sure but i think you should try [query orderByAscending:@"StartDate"] may it helps

Comment: Order is ok in my case. I'm using query. orderByAscending("createdAt"). The issue is I'll get duplicated items with my strategy if there are some updates in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more condition:

```
query.whereKey("createdAt",lessThanOrEqualTo:lastDate)
```

Probably is able to solve your problem. The ***lastDate*** is the date of your last record.

Comment: It only return 1 record. I found the query.skip is the one which affect the result. It seems the it "skips" some records.

Comment: I found a way based on your suggestion:
            query.whereKey("createdAt",lessThanOrEqualTo:lastDate)
            query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo:lastObjectId)